# regex/XSLT: replace specific string within boundaries

Tags: regex, xml, parsing, xslt, xml-parsing

I am not sure how to use regex to do the following:
within the edge tags (), check if `type="highway.secondary"`, and if yes, replace all values of speed to `40`.

```
<edge id="-100396051#2" type="highway.unclassified">
        <lane id="-100396051#2_0" index="0"  speed="13.89">
            <param key="origId" value="100396051"/>
        </lane>
    </edge>
    <edge id="-101784374#0" type="highway.secondary">
        <lane id="-101784374#0_0" index="0"  speed="27.78" length="17.22" >
            <param key="origId" value="101784374"/>
        </lane>
        <lane id="-101784374#0_1" index="1" speed="29.98" length="17.22" >
            <param key="origId" value="101784374"/>
        </lane>
    </edge>
```

So far I got this: 
`(?<=type="highway\.secondary")(speed)(?=edge)`, but that doesn't find speed...
Thanks!

Comment: Use an XML parser instead

Comment: My answer should solve your problem! It is based on XSLT technologies to parse the input XML and generate the desired XML output

Comment: Some call it [summoning the daemon](https://www.metafilter.com/86689/), others refer to it as [the Call for Cthulhu](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) and few just [turned mad and met the Pony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8344060). In short, never parse XML or HTML with a regex! Did you try an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet`, `xmllint` or `xsltproc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**INPUT:** `edges.xml`

```
<edges>
  <edge id="-100396051#2" type="highway.unclassified">
        <lane id="-100396051#2_0" index="0"  speed="13.89">
            <param key="origId" value="100396051"/>
        </lane>
    </edge>
    <edge id="-101784374#0" type="highway.secondary">
        <lane id="-101784374#0_0" index="0"  speed="27.78" length="17.22" >
            <param key="origId" value="101784374"/>
        </lane>
        <lane id="-101784374#0_1" index="1" speed="29.98" length="17.22" >
            <param key="origId" value="101784374"/>
        </lane>
    </edge>
</edges>
```

**STYLESHEET:** `change_speed.xsl`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@speed[../parent::edge and ../../@type='highway.secondary']">
    <xsl:attribute name="speed">
      <xsl:value-of select="'40'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ xsltproc change_speed.xsl edges.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edges>
  <edge id="-100396051#2" type="highway.unclassified">
        <lane id="-100396051#2_0" index="0" speed="13.89">
            <param key="origId" value="100396051"/>
        </lane>
    </edge>
    <edge id="-101784374#0" type="highway.secondary">
        <lane id="-101784374#0_0" index="0" speed="40" length="17.22">
            <param key="origId" value="101784374"/>
        </lane>
        <lane id="-101784374#0_1" index="1" speed="40" length="17.22">
            <param key="origId" value="101784374"/>
        </lane>
    </edge>
</edges>
```

**Explanations:**

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Will copy all the nodes and attributes recursively

```
<xsl:template match="@speed[../parent::edge and ../../@type='highway.secondary']">
    <xsl:attribute name="speed">
      <xsl:value-of select="'40'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

When you reach an attribute named `speed` for which the parent node is named `edge` and has an attribute `type` whose value is at `highway.secondary`, change the value of this attribute to `40`.